# Script runs slow processing stdout piped from service

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, pipe, stdout

I am using a utility named oscdump which listens on a specified port for OSC messages and prints the messages to stdout. I wish to parse and process these messages in a script however my script runs very unevenly, printing its output (as a test) in fits and starts.

Run on its own in a terminal, oscdump prints received messages in an even and rapidly responsive stream:

```
$ oscdump 12345
Running a server with port 12345
/param1 f 0.000000
/param1 f 0.000257
/param1 f 0.000534
/param1 f 0.000811
.... etc.
```

Inside my test script it's a different story, very uneven. Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $$ > /tmp/oscled.pid
ProcessMsg()
{
    while read msg
    do
    echo "Msg is $msg"
    done
}
oscdump 12345 | ProcessMsg

exit 0
```

What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `oscdump -L 12345` to disable stdout buffering.

Explanations:

- When stdout of a process is printed on a tty, the output is printed line by line, without any delay.
- When stdout of a process is redirected to a file or piped in another process stdin, buffering occurs to reduce the number of I/O operations.
- This increases performance in some cases, but also prevents the second process to receive the output in real-time.
- As a result, the second process will receive the output less often, in big batches, instead of frequently line-by-line.

See [this blog post](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) for a detailed technical explanation.

See also [that blog post](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering) for an example-driven explanation.

Comment: Many thanks. oscdump does not have an -L option, however I added fflush(stdout) in the source after the printf command, recompiled oscsend/oscdump and it has solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using `oscdump` from `liblo`. The version I tested (`liblo=0.29` from Debian Buster) has a `-L` option for addressing exactly this problem.